# How to make bubble icons like Opera Neon?

Tags: html, css

In Opera Neon, some websites have a custom "bubble" icon. See the image.

[image]

I'd like to have icons like these for my website. They are not related in any  way to the favicon or to the apple icons, I also checked the head of every website and I can't find nothing.

The questions are: how should i call the icon and where I should declare it? And what are the correct sizes?

Thanks!

Comment: indeed, i checked the pages souce code and nothing.

Comment: Do you mean the notification icon?

Comment: On what criteria are you basing the "yes" and "no," what are the meaningful differences? What HTML are you using, how far did your own CSS get you? What was wrong with it?

Comment: Was looking for the same thing @re1mansion. Hope you get an answer.

Comment: Given the answers so far I presume he refers to the main larger icon that normally has an automated screenshot but, in some cases, appears to be too carefully crafted to be so. But I wish people would care about their own questions and not just dump them here and let others play the guess game and do all the work.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into it as well.

**Short answer:** Opera Neon is using the [Open Graph og:image meta tag](http://ogp.me/) to show images in the bubble tabs.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/bubble-tab-image.png">
```

But I also think Opera Neon might have a specific meta tag for this which isn't documented yet.

**Long answer:**
The "bubble tabs" is mainly used to show images related to the page/article, and not icons like a fav icon. You'll see on the image you shared that the fav icon is already in the second bubble on the bubble tab.

For example if you click on an article on The Verge you will see the bubble tab is using the article's featured image as the "icon".

**Soultion:** I suspected that Opera Neon is using the Open Graph protocol to select the images. So if you're having a **og:image meta tag** (with a working source) on your website, Opera Neon will use this as the image in Bubble Tab. That is why bubble tab images may vary on different pages on a website.

To confirm that Opera Neon is using the images from og:image meta tag I ran some tests on a website where I changed the src in the og:image meta tag and noticed the image changed in the bubble tab. It took a while for the browser to scrape the new information, but it changed after a while (I'm still looking into how to force scraping new information).

I also noticed that most of the pages in the "Speed Dial" don't have a og:image meta tag on the front page. I've been looking through all of the meta tags and icon resources and didn't find any that could match the ones used in the "speed dial", so my conclusion is that those icons where added by default and not in the related webside source code. If you're adding your own website to the "speed dial" you will notice it will use the image from og:image meta tag or use a screenshot of the page if the meta tag is missing.

So my conclusion is that the bubble tabs are made for showing a featured image related to a page/article and is using Open Graph meta tags to handle this. But I also think Opera Neon might have a specific meta tag for this which isn't documented yet, so we just have be patient :)

Answer (score 0):

The **og:image meta tag** seems to be the only common factor in the example sites included with Opera Neon, but the don't match the bubble icons. For instance, if you manually link to Google or the New York Times, the new bubble icons are much bigger than the example bubbles (bubblicons?). The also have a smaller bubble, top left, containing the favicon whereas most of the example bubblicons do not. So it would appear that there is a second, hidden source where the bubblicons are being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I digged a bit in the compiled code of Opera Neon and, as far as I can see, the page icon is generated starting from the Facebook image `og:image`, falling back to the Twitter image `twitter:image` if the Facebook one is missing. I didn't find any custom metadata introduced by Opera Neon, but I would be happy to be wrong.

It also looks that they took some special care for the following websites (and this probably answer your question about why some website have a much nicer page icon):

- https://www.facebook.com/
- https://www.youtube.com/
- http://www.opera.com/blogs/
- http://www.theverge.com/
- https://soundcloud.com/
- https://dribbble.com/
- https://medium.com/
- http://mashable.com/
- http://www.nytimes.com/
- https://society6.com/
- http://www.wsj.com/
- https://www.theguardian.com/
- http://antyweb.pl/
- http://thenextweb.com/
- http://www.faz.net/
- http://www.giga.de/
- http://www.golem.de/
- http://www.independent.co.uk/
- http://www.makeuseof.com/
- http://www.pc-magazin.de/
- http://www.pcmag.com/
- http://www.pcwelt.de/
- http://www.reuters.com/
- http://www.spidersweb.pl/
- http://www.techradar.com/
- http://www.windowscentral.com/
- http://www.zdnet.com/
- https://techcrunch.com/
- https://www.buzzfeed.com/
- https://www.ghacks.net/
- https://www.wired.com/
- https://www.behance.net/
- http://www.webdesignernews.com/
- https://loqal.io/
- https://twitter.com/
- http://www.ebay.com/
- https://www.pinterest.com/
- http://4pda.ru/
- https://republic.ru/
- https://lifehacker.ru/
- http://www.computerbild.de/
- https://www.heise.de/
- http://www.chip.de/
- http://www.pcworld.com/
- https://www.engadget.com/
- http://www.digitaltrends.com/
- http://edition.cnn.com/tech/
- https://www.cnet.com/
- http://betanews.com/
- https://www.producthunt.com/
- http://www.vox.com/